# Linux Read and Write Permissions only through application

Tags: linux, apache, perl, permissions

I wrote a simple CGI web application to create a server log file to store the IP addresses which access my web page. My Cgi script location is

> '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/iplog.cgi'

My Log file location is,

> '/usr/share/log/iplog.txt'

My Question is, the log file 'iplog.txt' only should Read and Write through my application script 'iplog.cgi'. Now I gave permission as '777' to 'iplog.txt'. I know it will give permission to all to do anything. But I wish to Read and Write this file only through my cgi application script. How can i do this?

Comment: @Vadalasetti: Please delete your misinformation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such concept of giving an *application* permissions to read or write a file. Only users can.
Thus you need to give the logfile permissions so that only *the user that runs the cgi script* can read and write to it.

So if your cgi script is run by the (webserver's) user `www-data` (for example) then you need to:

```
sudo chown www-data /usr/share/log/iplog.txt
sudo chmod 600 /usr/share/log/iplog.txt
```

Then only the user `www-data` can read and write to the file.
Note that this also means that you (as user `dwayne`) cannot read the file, just as you asked.

To figure out the webserver's user you can issue

```
ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
```

Common apache users are `www-data`, `nobody`, `apache`.

Comment: Probably best to give permission to the admin group if you have one. (It's called `adm` on Ubuntu.) `chown www-data:adm ...` and `chmod 660 ...`